# Finding Total Memory in Bytes in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

In my assignment I am expected that **Print the total memory in bytes required for the dynamic array**

I have to read the file and find required byte. 
**And also it is not my assignment main purpose**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>

#define N 100 //Change this acording to the size of the file.
#define PATH "list.txt"



int * read_array(char *filename,int *count);


int main(void){
    int *arr,count;
    arr=read_array(PATH,&count);
    int byte_used= count * sizeof(int);
    printf("%d number of byte used\n",byte_used);
    free(arr);
}

int * read_array(char *filename, int *i){
    FILE *fp=fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp==NULL){ printf("File does not exist\n"); *i=0 return 0;  }
    int a=0,counter=1;

    int *arr;
    arr=(int*)malloc(counter*N*sizeof(int));

    while(fscanf(fp,"%d,",&arr[a]) == 1){
        a++;
        /* When all allocated memory is filed, do this */
        if (counter*N<=a){
            counter++;
            arr=(int*)realloc(arr,counter*N*sizeof(int));
        }

    }

    *i=a; //returns how many numbers in this file
    return arr;
}
```

So I am wondering in 3rd line in main is valid for expectations or there is another way to find the usage of byte?
Also I will do the same thing with using linked list. So we learning dynamic memory allocation.

little example of list.txt

```
107557,55092,62318,70428,176047,80485,54378,196442,189223,30437,60540,192159,33269,76106,45347,157100,146714,148826,117640,101563,76183,37355,182131,177126,194497,183527,194987,38558,33858,32845,125977,63521,119818,152605,188990,76983,129104,6248,16584,166616,130089,18922,24273,156750,101204,196746,188582,120890,74983,112513,129785,77139,173710,29203,113654,65771,190139,133410,130882,120492,50775,137392,165089,105591,147175,57138,61213,112020,180819,90229,89965,90348,113128,61010,141313,6982,59301,136882,16740,35281,120563,10840,112388,72077,136377,26905,171965,101848,112372,107374,153418,113139,37599,122005,53904,101215,86164,38777,122907,16655,115439,153224,25420,193267,115505,89156,156848,137102,31725,19419,25086,105131,144132,40022,143155,99377,31892,831,139379,191996,162653,82880,170260,61363,80250,115883,117688,92847,184991,49799,122085,21224,48320,48359,119315,96627,159768,80137,93466,15103,174821,83863,129759,173513,118821,63486,77311,87648,23289,12885,39730,89500,58910,136438,118109,175974,7664,160314,98305,78389,31732,24061,160832,3729,61192,112101,129654,180326,59920,165289,58643,107106,44683,54488,175689,7988,70030,52949,89169,112724,181046,144363,56838,100020,26208,118902,197054,186915,2010,76672,194157,23433,166280,88101,85856,91119,57961,33077,198816,111023,55898,75583,58333,153127,20589,14342,61971,127062,1377,34588,131515,121206,110805,3851,172936,72173,73173,175725,21785,68748,6056,80365,24673,125787,105702,181725,175734,32495,178036,137669,63675,444,164708,191622,156968,62629,131119,84594,8586,124567,116197,75871,49064,1049,27621,108219,16135,176144,43276,198582,117926,33090,128903,70690,11719,43055,42658,46582,150291,14896,138883,44807,83779,26870,192992,183926,54984,165114,138820,139714,20630,85346,16490,96596,111548,138552,159941,48643,160220,149088,126113,173179,79943,7088,187176,36160,53923,111483,91996,38794,78371,148969,43052,56343,32518,1922,64291,23974,191324,1011,182138,197160,154265,15338,140128,76576,51349,150257,149451,5498,184812,178437,56529,179679,158530,165798,141758,84579,188457,7807,154972,51980,78319,13982,131312,143826,143181,33524,15063,81554,15272,124150,28990,168269,40077,112055,1340,90010,144856,152767,131248,59260,73587,36615,36189,167944,145935,68244,180668,35806,4456,152727,57047,120876,41564,193295,176540,168954,23092,28061,1541,58999,115210,97097,148034,54665,102469,152367,56568,145834,33905,44792,173362,16842,78441,174358,34009,174751,114538,122805,167504,179079,58505,28972,164371,136677,39996,179655,24916,199296,189433,108802,183450,136978,109015,167131,29554,12661,68967,189654,27690,45662,149812,48602,17899,130212,102263,89393,133828,178975,52897,120831,32563,95749,109746,184058,197708,140014,164609,145017,103794,98801,148181,102247,55108,128686,75497,127044,185145,66265,67860,140704,10899,114890,103232,12392,116319,180102,132965,146363,177084,191390,190615,44790,51776,31505,135222,12767,113621,40095,73462,142896,152514,
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what your problem is. Does the code you have work? As a suggestion, maybe you could check the size of the file using `fseek(...)` and `ftell(...)` and related functions? Also, you may like to read up on the `realloc(...)` function.

Comment: @AdrianMole Actually, My code is working fine, Also finding size is not the mine main point in this assignment. I wondering, Is finding total memory in bytes this? What am I doing in main 4th line is correct to find total memory in bytes?

Comment: My only 'critique' would be that you should have the `a++;` line *before* the `if (counter*N<a){` check.

Comment: @AdrianMole Ok, I updated my code parts which does not related to my question. Thanks, but I do not get my answer yet.

Comment: The fscanf should test `== 1`, not `!= EOF`

Comment: Almost any [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) will tell you what the `sizeof` operator does; and you seem happy that `count` is your number of items, so what is left to doubt? Maybe you should use the [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) type, rather than `int` for `byte_used` and `count`, but that's only going to cause problems for very big datasets.

Comment: @M.M Thanks to you too for correcting me, Is there any answer for my question? Or my question is so dumb?

Comment: @muhammedoğuz The size looks good, but... `if (fp==NULL)` leaves `*i` unassigned. `if (counter*N<a)` should be `<=`.

Comment: The amount of memory that your array is using is the last allocation size that you passed to `realloc`.

Comment: @user3386109 Right, but not all of the elements are necessarily filled in. I guess it depends on how you read "*bytes* ***required*** *for the dynamic array*".

Comment: @dxiv I was reading *"Print the **total** memory in bytes"*, and given that the OP intends to compare with the memory used by a linked list, it seems only fair to include the wasted overhead.

Comment: @dxiv I edited code due to your directions. user3386109  thx for the answers. So you guys think I should leave the cod like this or what?

Comment: @muhammedoğuz You'll have to decide whether what you want to count is the size allocated to the array vs. the (potentially smaller) size actually occupied by the numbers that you read in. Or add an `if (a < counter*N) arr=(int*)realloc(arr,a*sizeof(int));` before returning, which would discard the unused part at the end of the array.

Comment: @dxiv it is very make sense. I will do like that, you can reply as an answer this.

Comment: @muhammedoğuz Glad it helped. There wasn't much left to answer by the time I got here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third line in your code is enough for you, but if you want to make your code better you can something line;

```
if( a < counter*N )    arr=(int*)realloc( arr, a*sizeof(int) );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the question text:

> **Assignment**:  Print the total memory in bytes required for the dynamic array

With that assignment you can simplify your code a lot.

Something like:

```
int getIntsRequired(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) return 0;

    int tmp;
    int counter = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d,", &tmp) == 1) ++counter;
    fclose(fp);
    return counter;
}

size_t getBytesRequired(char *filename)
{
    return sizeof(int) * getIntsRequired(filename);
}

int main(void){
    size_t bytes_required = getBytesRequired(YOUR_FILE_NAME);
    printf("%zu number of byte required\n", bytes_required);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer but It is not my assignment purpose, just one of the smallest parts. I mentioned in comment section although I edited my question.

Comment: @muhammedoğuz If your assignment requires that you also save the ints in an array, you should state that clearly in your question.